# How to print text underneath an input prompt in Python?

Tags: python, command-line, user-input

I am making a text-based RPG. I want to display the player's stats (health, damage, and so on) underneath the input prompt for their action, like so:

```
Please enter your action: 
>>> <user typing in prompt here>
HP: 20 DMG: 10
```

How/what libraries do I need to achieve this?

Comment: Check out the `readline` library or something like that. It's not possible in vanilla python

Comment: i'm not an expert, but i think that's not possible. the user input pauses script execution at it's point, so everything below that input is only executed after having made that input. maybe you change your "interface" and show this values right on top?

Comment: It's definitely possible, using something as [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), which BTW is in the standard library. But it's gonna be more complex than printing the text above the input, because you'll basically need to design a console GUI.

Comment: xph I thought about that, I was wondering if I could move the user input prompt to above where the text is displayed?

Comment: @ipsascientiapotestas: then you'll need to program a console GUI, like 'Right leg' mentioned. could be a little much, for this - but in the end, this will be handy for other things, too, i guess :)

Comment: @xph my aim here is to learn new things. If I need to learn to program a custom console GUI, then that is what I shall do. Also, if someone wraps up how to do what I want in an answer, thatd be great. Until then I'll just browse the python docs for answers

Answer (score 2):

You could use curses, and do something similar to this:

```py
import curses
from curses import wrapper
def main(std): # The 'std' causes the main function to inherit std
  curses.echo()
  std.addstr(2, 0, "HP: ... DMG: ...")
  std.addstr(0, 0, ">>>")
  action=std.getstr(0, 4, 100000)
wrapper(main)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: can you show where you're getting the ```std``` variable?  The OP may be wondering, "where did this std come from?"  That's no fun

Comment: it is for some reason required by `curses`, you can replace the `std` with anything, but you must replace **every** `std` with the new word, otherwise you get an error: `NameError: name 'addstr' is not defined`

Answer (score -3):

are you finding about input

```
v= input('Please enter your action:')
print (v)
```

Comment: The input works, but what I want is to display health before whilst they are typing, not after