# How to print text after the input prompt while input is still happening?

Tags: python, terminal, user-input

I am trying to get things to print after the input area in python so that I can get something like this:

```
-----------------------------------
 > (this is where this input is)
-----------------------------------
```

This is my original snippet:

```
input("-----------------------------------\n > "); print("-----------------------------------")
```

I am asking if there is a way to get things to print before the user hits enter while `input()` is getting input.

Comment: and what is happening ?

Comment: The input line is not allowing the next line to be printed on before the user hits enter

Comment: no I am asking what is happening in your case, coz I run the code you provided and it shows me what you are expecting

Comment: I don't think this is something you can do - not into the terminal anyway. If you want prettier interactions, look into stuff like tkinter I guess

Comment: Ok thanks, i thought of tkinter or pyautogui but those seem like a bigger step in what i need.

Comment: @ashish singh, Ill edit the post rq. I dont know why but stack edited it or something to match standards or wtv

Comment: thanks for adding the details.. can you explain what is the use case where you want to do this ?

Comment: Like just a more visually appealing input area in some of my projects or when i need to embed an input area in an area with a greater amount of info with no room near the bottom of my terminal window. like very specific use cases but this would be that little extra thing to complete whatever it may be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print text underneath an input prompt in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919955/how-to-print-text-underneath-an-input-prompt-in-python)