# Printing below an input before the user enters the input

Tags: python, input

I'm creating a text-based game using Python but I want to be able to print information below the input before they enter it. Example:

```
Enter your input: _
Health: 50 Hunger: 100
```

They type on the input line but can see the health counter before they enter.

So the Health and Hunger counter is printed as they type.

I have not tried much but here is some code:

```py
userInput = input("Enter your name:")
print(f"Health: {playerHealth} Hunger: {playerHunger}")
```

Comment: Feature like that is OS and Terminal specific - python ships with curses module for Mac & Linux but   not for Windows but do check; https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html  -- More "portable" way would be to use something like rich - https://github.com/Textualize/rich

Comment: There is another thread on how to do this here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919955/how-to-print-text-underneath-an-input-prompt-in-python

Comment: @jazzyoda5 which also points to curses but that said, curses does not ship with windows version of python.